# Updating Rails 5 Initializer with Devise User Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I thought I was getting closer to wrapping my head around Rails until this challenge. I have an initializer `agilecrm.rb` - content show below.  I am using [AgileCRM Ruby code](https://github.com/agilecrm/ruby-on-rails#intro) to try and connect my app with AgileCRM system. When using the code below, with the test `Create Contact` array at the bottom, it successfully creates a contact in my AgileCRM account, so I know at least this part works.  What I need to do is create a new AgileCRM user every time I create a new Devise user. I have a feeling that I am looking at this the wrong way and probably need a controller for this, but this is not completely foreign to me, but I still can't figure out when way to go.  Thank you.

**config/initializers/agilecrm.rb**

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

class AgileCRM
  class << self
    def api_key=(key)
      @@api_key = key
    end

    def domain=(d)
      @@domain = d
    end

    def email=(email)
      @@email = email
    end

    def api_key
      @@api_key
    end

    def domain
      @@domain
    end

    def email
      @@email
    end

    def request(method, subject, data = {})
      path = "/dev/api/#{subject}"
      case method
        when :get
          request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(path)
        when :post
          request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(path)
          request.body = data.to_json
        when :put
          request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(path)
          request.body = data.to_json
        when :delete
          request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(path)
        else
          raise "Unknown method: #{method}"
      end
      uri = URI.parse("https://#{domain}.agilecrm.com")
      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      http.use_ssl = true
      http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
      request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      request['Accept'] = 'application/json'
      request.basic_auth AgileCRM.email, AgileCRM.api_key
      response = http.request(request)
      response.body
    end
  end
end

AgileCRM.api_key = '*******'
AgileCRM.domain = '*******'
AgileCRM.email = '*******'

#  ======================Create Contact====================================

contact_data = '{
    "star_value": "4",
    "lead_score": "92",
    "tags": [
        "Lead",
        "Likely Buyer"
    ],
    "properties": [
        {
            "type": "SYSTEM",
            "name": "first_name",
            "value": "John"
        }
    ]
}'
parsed_contact_data = JSON.parse(contact_data)
print(AgileCRM.request :post, 'contacts', parsed_contact_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to move this logic into your `User` model, and have a `after_save` hook to push data to `agilecrm`. Assuming that the Devise user model is called `User` :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  after_save :sync_to_agilecrm

  def sync_to_agilecrm
    # your agilecrm api calls go here
    ...
  end

end
```

The above should do what you are trying to achieve.